# Attribute to apply to non-OK responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017

If I have controller GET methods, such as:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("accountrecv({accountid})/promisepay", Name = "GetPromisePay")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPromisePay(int accountid)
    {
        var query = Request.RequestUri.Query;
        var uri = new Uri(Client.Instance.BaseAddress.ToString() + accountid + "/promisepay" + query);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = uri, Method = HttpMethod.Get };
        var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(request);
        return response.Result;
    }
```

How can I impose behavior on all responses where the `HttpStatusCode` is NOT ok?

I imagine I would create an attribute at the method level, such as:

```
[NonOKResponse]
[HttpGet]
[Route.......]
public HttpResponseeMessage GetPromisePay(int accountid)
{
//my code
return response.Result //but force it here to return 404 for EVERY response other than 200
}
```

**How can I define an attribute that I can use on all GETs to force a specific response based on some criteria?**

Comment: Why not just check the status code of `response` before returning result?

Comment: because i have hundreds of controllers and possibly thousands of methods against which i would need to apply thisi behavior

Comment: Would an ActionFilter implementing [`IResultFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iresultfilter(v=vs.118).aspx) work here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) answers your question.  You can use the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` to handle and manage exceptions.  For example:

```
public class GeneralExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a Result Filter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs